# Not able to access file via tcl code

Tags: tcl

I am having a file test.txt on desktop, i want to access it via code and read the code i have tried below mentioned code but getting same error could not open file no such file or directory exist. Kindly take a look at my code :

```
set filename {C:\Users\E505135\Desktop\test.txt}
set fp [open $filename r]
set file_data [read $fp]
close $fp
set data [split $file_data ","]
foreach line $data {
puts "$line";
}
```

FYI i have tried both forward slash and back slash in code still getting same error.

Comment: I'm on a windows system where I similarly have a user name comprised of a letter followed by 6 digits but I have *no problem* running the following: `set filename {C:\Users\c829454\Desktop\test.txt}; set fp [open $filename r]; close $fp`

Comment: I get no issues using forward or back slashes. Are you sure you've got the right path? Is the script in the same directory as the file? You could try the command `set cdir [pwd]; set filename "$cdir/text.txt"` (`pwd` returns the current path of the script as a string).

Comment: From the command prompt, try `type C:\Users\E505135\Desktop\test.txt` and what do you see? Is the file really there?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing apparently wrong in your code; it looks absolutely fine. The only real possibility is that the file isn't really where you think it is. Unfortunately, this is [quite possible on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and I'm not on the deployments of Windows where this is actually happens, so I can't test my theory).

The easiest way around this may be to use Tk's `tk_getOpenFile` to provide the filename to process rather than hard-coding it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tclsh via cygwin on windows, your path will be /cygdrive/c/Users/E505135/Desktop/test.txt (case-sensitive).

I tried your code as is (just copied and pasted) in Windows 7 under Strawberry, and in Fedora 18 (with path modification). Both ran fine.